# How Hibernate/Jpa differs transient and detached instance/object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sessionfactory, hibernate-session

Actually these two are very good questions:

[How Hibernate differs transient and detached entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426067/how-hibernate-differs-transient-and-detached-entities)

[Check for detached entity in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731816/check-for-detached-entity-in-hibernate)

I have actually read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview) many time, and check some posts in stackoverflow. A lot of answers are just copied from the persistence state definition without further explanation.

Let see the example below:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.id = 123; // 123 identifier exist in database.
person.name = "abc";
```

Hibernate doc state that for a `transient` instance, it must be:

- instantiated using the new operator
- has no persistent representation in the database
- no identifier value has been assigned

This doesn't look like a transient instance, it doesn't fulfill the definition.

It doesn't look like a detached instance too, obviously it is not detached from a closed session.

So, is this a transient or detached instance?

Comment: As I understand ... (no identifier value has been assigned) by or registered to the persistence context

Comment: also check my answer to one of the questions you mentioned :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426067/how-hibernate-differs-transient-and-detached-entities/48926627#48926627

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your answer, do you mean, hibernate track the instance whether it is transient or detached by their identifier only?

Comment: It seems to be keeping record of previously detached entities somehow

Answer (score 0):

from Pro JPA 2.1 :

> An entity has a persistent identity when there exists a representation of it in the data store; that is, a
>   row in a database table. If it is not in the database, then even though the in-memory entity may have its identity set in
>   a field, it does not have a persistent identity

So persistence id is only considered after the entity is already persisted, not by assigning a value to the id element

Comment: So base on my example, it is a transient or detached instance?

Comment: transient (aka new)